# require.js is requesting html files but serving them as script elements

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, cors

I'm using the require.js text plugin with the text! syntaxt to render xhr responses as html.

```
text       : 'libs/require/text' ...
```

In my views I have defined them as

```
define([
    'text!templates/categories.html'
    , 'models/Categories'
    , 'views/CategoryView'
    ], ...
```

Everything works as it should locally.

However when I pushed this code to a server it started loading the *.html as `<script></script>` elements.

Further more, it was attaching a .js extension to the .html file name as well.

ANy thoughts? The assets being loaded are CORS.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue by forcing the text! plugin to configure as ALWAY perform CORS.

To do that I added the following:

```
 require.config({
     text: {
          useXhr: function (u,p,h,p) {
               return true;
           }
      }, ...
```

My guess to it being an issue with CORS was correct. It wasn't until I narrowed it down to the text plugin did I see it was trying load assets local.

I also could have rememdied this issue by doing the following.

```
define([
'text!http://location.com/to/external/domain/aka/cors/templates/categories.html'
, 'models/Categories'
, 'views/CategoryView'
], ...
```

where I explicitly tell require and the text plugin to load these files from afar.

Erik