# External template on remote server (via http)

Tags: templates, knockout.js

I am using the koExternalTemplateEngine to load external templates.

This works fine when the template is located in the same site or served from another site on the same server.

However when I try to reference a template on a remote server it doesn't work.  I get http 200 ok but with a status code of 0 (there is nothing in the Response and no html).

A code example is below:

```
<script src="Content/Scripts/ko/lib/koExternalTemplateEngine_all.js"></script> 
<script>infuser.defaults.templateSuffix = ".tmpl.html";
infuser.defaults.templateUrl = "http://www.anotherServer.com/koTemplates";</script>
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'koTemplate1' }"></div>
```

Is it possible to reference a template on a remote server and if so what am I missing?

Comment: This is a restriction in `$.ajax`/browsers that you cannot send requests to different servers from javascript: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201429/jquery-ajax-fails-when-url-is-from-different-server

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you go down the route of using requireJS and its text plugin for loading external cross origin content and configure the xhr use there:

```
config: {
        text: {
            useXhr: function (url, protocol, hostname, port) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

you can use this property in requirejs config to set it to use xhr and activate CORS.

Make sure that this doesnt work in ie 6 and 7 and for ie 8 and 9 you need to use:

```
window.XDomainRequest
```

Once you did all this you can simlpy call your external template as a requirejs module dependency like this:

```
define("moduleName", ["ko", "text!templates/surveys.html"], 
function(html){
    $('body').append(html);
    ko.applyBindings(new viewmodel)...
});
```

Some good links for you:
[require.js is requesting html files but serving them as script elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002182/require-js-is-requesting-html-files-but-serving-them-as-script-elements)

https://github.com/requirejs/text

[Configuring xdr for IE](https://gist.github.com/michaelcox/2655118)

Comment: It looks like I'm going to be hosting the template on the same server now so problem solved.  I'll keep this in mind for the future though, thanks.